# select data mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have in my table places named field. there are space separated values(there are problem to store csv value in one field). now i want to fire query like below. how i can do ??

```
select * from tablename where variablename in places
```

i did try this way but it shows syntax error.

```
select * from tablename where variablename in replace(places,' ',',')



### places ###

bank finance point_of_interest establishment
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: thanks to all for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to normalise your data structure and do not have a single field storing multiple values.

You can make a query work without normalisation, but any solutions would be lot less optimal from a performance point of view.

1. Use patter matching with `like` operator:

   `... where fieldname like '% searched_value %'`
2. Use the replace() function and combine it with [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

   `... where find_in_set('searched_value',replace(fieldname,' ',','))>0`

Answer (score 1):

Use **FIND_IN_SET**

For comma separated

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE  ( FIND_IN_SET( 'bank', variablename ) )
```

> Refer : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fbcd/1)

For space separated

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE  ( FIND_IN_SET( 'bank', replace(variablename,' ',',') ) )
```

> Refer : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63754e/1)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think your problem comes from the usage of IN
IN for MySql is used like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (bank,finance,point_of_interest, establishment);
```

In case of you want to select places you need to specify each place into value like

Comment: i want reverse of it and also my values are space separated. this way

`SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE var_name in (bank finance point_of_interest establishment)` <- this is my single field value named places